# Is there a PHP function to count the number of times a value occurs within an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to count the number of times a value occurs in a given array.

For example:

```
$array = array(5, 5, 2, 1);

// 5 = 2 times
// 2 = 1 time
// 1 = 1 time
```

Does such a function exist?  If so, please point me to it in the php docs... because I can't seem to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values).

```
$array = array(5, 5, 2, 1);
$counts = array_count_values($array); // Array(5 => 2, 2 => 1, 1 => 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)